# Need advice regarding jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to read data from a json file using ajax jquery and display it as a table in html.This is working fine.But,then,I must be able to click button on every row to display the child nodes of each row as an alert from the showDetails function mentioned below.I am unable to get the data.Instead it shows an error in console "childNode.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: mylapore is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (childNode.html:1)".TIA

childNode.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8">  
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style>
table {
    width: 50%;
}
th {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 6px;
}
td {
    background: #f9f9f9;
    padding: 6px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">

function myFunction(){
 $.ajax({
   url: 'childNode.json',
   type: 'GET',
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   dataType: 'json',
    success: function(childNode) {
        //console.log(childNode);
        var length=childNode.length;
        for (var i=0; i<length; i++) {
            //alert("hii");
            console.log(childNode[i].cityDetails.area);
            var area=childNode[i].cityDetails.area;
            alert(area);
              var row = '<tr>'
                row+= '<td>'+ childNode[i].name+ '</td>'
                row+= '<td>'+ childNode[i].age+ '</td>'
                row+= '<td>'+ childNode[i].country+ '</td>'
                row+= '<td>'+ childNode[i].state + '</td>'
                row+= '<td>'+ childNode[i].city + '</td>'
                row+= '<td><button onclick="JavaScript:showDetails('+area+');">' + 'View Details' + '</button></td>'
                row+= '</tr>';
            $('#myTable').append(row); 
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
       // alert('Error: ' + textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown);
    }
}); 
}
function showDetails(text)
{
    alert(text);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction();">
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>age</th>
        <th>country</th>
        <th>state</th>
        <th>city</th>
        <th>action</th>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

childNode.json

```
[
    {
        "name":"shruthy",
        "age":"31",
        "country":"india",
        "state":"tamilnadu",
        "city":"chennai",
        "cityDetails":
            {
                "area":"mylapore",
                 "station":"kilpauk"
            }

    },
    {
        "name":"arsha",
        "age":"31",
        "country":"india",
        "state":"tamilnadu",
        "city":"bengaluru",
        "cityDetails":
            {
                "area":"koramangala",
                 "station":"cantonment"
            }

    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly note that you're including jQuery multiple times. One of the references can be removed.

With regard to the issue, it's to do with the value in the argument you provide to the function requiring quotes around it. The correct syntax would be:

```js
row += '<td><button onclick="JavaScript:showDetails(\"' + area + '\");">' + 'View Details' + '</button></td>';
```

**However** a much better approach is to avoid using inline event handlers, as they are bad practice due to being outdated and not following the separation of concerns principle. Instead use delegated event handlers. As you're already including jQuery in the page, it would look like this:

```js
// mock AJAX response data:
let childNode = [{
  "name": "shruthy",
  "age": "31",
  "country": "india",
  "state": "tamilnadu",
  "city": "chennai",
  "cityDetails": {
    "area": "mylapore",
    "station": "kilpauk"
  }
}, {
  "name": "arsha",
  "age": "31",
  "country": "india",
  "state": "tamilnadu",
  "city": "bengaluru",
  "cityDetails": {
    "area": "koramangala",
    "station": "cantonment"
  }
}]

// inside success(childNode)
let html = childNode.map(n => {
  let row = '<tr>'
  row += '<td>' + n.name + '</td>'
  row += '<td>' + n.age + '</td>'
  row += '<td>' + n.country + '</td>'
  row += '<td>' + n.state + '</td>'
  row += '<td>' + n.city + '</td>'
  row += '<td><button class="showdata" data-area="' + n.cityDetails.area + '">View Details</button></td>'
  row += '</tr>';
  return row;
});
$('#myTable').append(html);

// somewhere outside the AJAX call:
$('#myTable').on('click', '.showdata', function() {
  console.log($(this).data('area'));
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 50%;
}

th {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 6px;
}

td {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>age</th>
    <th>country</th>
    <th>state</th>
    <th>city</th>
    <th>action</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's a full example showing the entire HTML structure:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
  <style>
    /* NOTE: This should be in an external .css file */
    
    table {
      width: 50%;
    }
    
    th {
      background: #f1f1f1;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 6px;
    }
    
    td {
      background: #f9f9f9;
      padding: 6px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript">
    jQuery($ => {
      $('#myTable').on('click', '.showdata', function() {
        console.log($(this).data('area'));
      });

      $.ajax({
        url: 'childNode.json',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(childNode) {
          let html = childNode.map(n => {
            let row = '<tr>'
            row += '<td>' + n.name + '</td>'
            row += '<td>' + n.age + '</td>'
            row += '<td>' + n.country + '</td>'
            row += '<td>' + n.state + '</td>'
            row += '<td>' + n.city + '</td>'
            row += '<td><button class="showdata" data-area="' + n.cityDetails.area + '">View Details</button></td>'
            row += '</tr>';
            return row;
          });
          $('#myTable').append(html);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          // alert('Error: ' + textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown);
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>age</th>
      <th>country</th>
      <th>state</th>
      <th>city</th>
      <th>action</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I replaced the line as mentioned by you.But, it says 
"2childNode.html:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" upon button click